# How to get the cumulative weight (and score, height, depth) of a transaction?

Tags: transaction, iri-legacy-api

I know that I can get the weight of a transaction by converting the transaction hash into trits and count the trailing number of zeros.

```
import iota

def get_transaction_weight(transaction_hash):
     transaction_hash_trits = iota.TryteString.as_trits(iota.TransactionHash(transaction_hash))
     transaction_hash_trits_string = ''.join(map(str, transaction_hash_trits))
     transaction_hash_trits_without_trailing_zeros_string = transaction_hash_trits_string.rstrip('0')
     transaction_weight = len(transaction_hash_trits_string) - len(transaction_hash_trits_without_trailing_zeros_string)
     print('Weight: %d (Transaction: %s)' % (transaction_weight, transaction_hash))

some_transaction_hash = 'VYNEUMNUV9BTLUDAKDC9XYVEDHMTCDHBCXCNOWELCSSHFESBYCUFOSGDJIUEQMSVJKZQIQIBQTDXZ9999'

get_transaction_weight(some_transaction_hash)
```

In the [IOTA whitepaper](https://iota.org/IOTA_Whitepaper.pdf) (page 5) the concepts of cumulative weight, score, depth and height of a transaction are introduced. Is this information available in practice or are these primarily theoretical concepts? One could walk the tangle. But that would take a lot of time, as one would need to walk every possible path from a transaction towards the genesis to get its score and height (as one needs to find the longest path to the genesis). Getting the cumulative weight and depth of a particular transaction is even more difficult as one would need to find all tips that directly or indirectly confirm this transaction (again to find the longest path to a tip).

So is there a way of getting any/all of cumulative weight, score, height and depth from the IOTA api for a particular transaction? Will there ever be?